# What is the difference when we initialize TextWatcher from method and directly?

Tags: java, android

Method 1:When I initialize text watcher directly 'etOtp1MobNoVer' is not null.

```
private final TextWatcher otp1TextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s != null)
            checkNProceedForTextChanged(etOtp1MobNoVer, s);
    }
};
```

Method 2: When I initialize TextWathcer from method etOtp1MobNoVer is null.

```
private final TextWatcher otp1TextWatcher = textWatcher(etOtp1MobNoVer);

@NonNull
private TextWatcher textWatcher(ET etOtp1MobNoVer) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s != null)
                checkNProceedForTextChanged(etOtp1MobNoVer, s);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey,
There is not a lots of differences between them only syntax pattern  is different.

Comment: Please add etOtp1MobNoVer initialization code

Comment: etOtp1MobNoVer  is EditText (a view). 
Initialize like 
@BindView(R.id.etOtp1MobNoVer )
EditText etOtp1MobNoVer ;

Comment: It will be initialized probably in `onCreate` by ButterKnife. So in case of method initialization which will be invoke before, your `etOtp1MobNoVer` will be null.